# Is there any solution to change the behavior of select box in IE without jquery

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, behavior

I'm trying to have a select box which behaves similar with all browsers.. Is there any solution without using jquery plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default look for select boxes is different for IE. u cannot have the similar look without using jquery!

Anywyz, as grsmto said.. using appearance css property is a good option to customize it using css!

Answer (score 0):

No.

But behavior should be the same, except the look. Depending on the browsers you are targeting you could try to use the `appearance` css property to customize it without JS.

Comment: I mean i want to change the default look of select box in ie. I have seen the following which i'm not interested to add to my project. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/